# Do there exist finite 4-regular graphs with shortest cycle length $\ell$ for all sufficiently large $\ell$?

Tags: graph-theory

Do there exist finite 4-regular graphs with shortest cycle length $\ell$ for all sufficiently large $\ell$?  I wanted a way to construct one with shortest cycle length $10$ but I realised I wasn't even sure such a graph existed.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cage_(graph_theory)) there is an $r$-regular graph of girth $g$ for every $r\geq2$ and $g\geq3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Google Ramanujan graphs. There are explicit constructions of $4$-regular Ramanujan graphs, where the length $\ell$ of the smallest cycle can be bounded from below by $\ell \ge \frac{4 \log_3 N}{3}$ where $N$ is the number of vertices.

If you need a graph where the length of the smallest cycle is *precisely* $\ell$, then use the above and take a Ramanujan graph with a sufficiently large number of vertices e.g., the length of the smallest cycle is at least $4\ell$ and put an edge between two vertices of distance $\ell-1$ from each other; you can check that this induces no smaller cycles than that.